# Setting a different title tag for a URL with a hash?

Tags: html, seo, title

I am wondering if it is possible to set a unique Title tag for a URL with a hash.

For instance, can I have a title for this page:

http://somesite.com

And then have a separate title for this url:

http://somesite.com#something

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Only with Javascript.

Comment: Normally, the search engines ignore everything after the hashtag because it's usually content contained on the same page or URL.

Comment: By definition, a fragment identifier specifies a location or element inside the page, and it is handled by browsers. Search engines read the page title as specified in markup.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be helpful:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var url =document.URL; 
            if(url.indexOf('#')!=-1){
                document.title = "This is the new page title.";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
     <body>
         <a href="?#something">SomeLink</a>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: @APAD1, the question was tagged with “seo”. Do you expect this to help anything with search engines? It is unrealistic to expect them to execute JavaScript code on pages (though they might do it some day – to detect attempts at fooling them).